What does "inside the check-in cutoff time" mean?
I read about a passenger who was refused boarding:

So she had to wait in line for the kiosk, but the line was too long and by the time she made it to the front she was inside the check-in cutoff time. They wouldn’t even let her check in and run to the gate at this point – she was just turned away.

What does "inside the check-in cutoff time" mean? I know what a check-in is, but I thought a cutoff was point in time inside and not a period in time, so I don't understand what inside a cutoff means.

Your cited example By the time she made it to the front she was inside the check-in cutoff time isn't idiomatic. By the time [something happened] is a "negative polarity" element that's always followed by something "undesirable". By the time I got to the airport, the plane had already taken off (bad outcome; I missed my flight).

@FumbleFingers thanks that's great to know, I was unaware of the concept of "negative polarity" elements and I didn't know that by the time was one of them.

@FumbleFingers I don't think "negative polarity" is always right. "By the time I alerted the rescuers the missing hiker had turned up safe". That isn't undesirable.

@DJClayworth: Perhaps "undesirable" isn't always the right word - sometimes it's more like "against expectations" (thereby "negating" earlier actions or hopes). But I still think they're all "negative polarity" that somehow contrast antecedent and actual outcome.

There are time slots for boarding, technically. That's why it's fine. You are inside the time covered by the time slot.

If there is a cutoff time, it means that anyone who is after that time will be "cut off".  If you are inside the cutoff time, you are before that time, so you don't get cut off.
For example, in a marathon, there may be a cutoff time of 6 hours.  If have not finished the marathon inside of six hours, then the race is over and you will be counted as "did not finish".  If you are inside of the cutoff time, then you should get a finisher's medal etc.
Similar for boarding an airplane, there is a cutoff time. If you are not at the gate inside of that time, then the airplane will leave without you.
However in context this means the exact opposite. She was inside the time in the negative sense of being inside the time when you don't get to board.  As always, read the context, not the words.

Got it, thanks!

You may have missed a "not". The passage says " she was inside the check-in cutoff time. They wouldn’t even let her check in". So if you are at the gate inside that time the plane will leave without you.

@DJClayworth That's a quote from the source. I think the source missed a negation somewhere.

Maybe, maybe not. We should at least check with the OP.

I didn't miss it, it was edited into the question an hour after my answer was written

@DJClayworth If by OP you mean me and not the author of the quote, the current quote is confusing me. That's partly why I had taken a smaller quote in my original question (which also confused me, but less). But James'' answer is 100% clear.

Presumably the sense is 'the cutoff time is 30 minutes before take off and she got to the desk less than 30 minutes before', i.e. 'inside' the time. Could have been better expressed.

There is an unfortunate polarity interpretation in this answer. In the OP, inside the cutoff time means “after the critical moment and therefore disaqualified.” But in the marathon example here, inside the cutoff time means “before the critical moment and therefore qualified.” Anyway, I agree with @KateBunting, the original sentence cited in the OP is poorly expressed.

yes, I looked at the source, and the context is clear. She was too late to board the flight. "inside" here means "in the time when you can't fly" not "inside the time when you can fly".  Read the Context.#

@JamesK  I don't understand. Does that mean that "she was inside the check-in cutoff time." is ambiguous, and we need the context to disambiguate?

The meaning that I expected is contradicted by the context, so I "read the context"

Example:
The check-in cut-off time is: 3 p.m.
That means you have to check in before 3 p.m.
A cut-off time is a time on a clock, so to speak, when you can no longer do something.
The underlying idea here is that there is a time slot for doing something. This is especially true for cruise ships.
The time slot could be: 1 p.m. to 2:45 p.m. and if you are inside it, you are on time. BUT if you are inside the cut-off time, you arrived after 2:45 and they will not let you board.
The example below is for the web, but the same idea applies to the question:

Lufthansa is extending web check-in time slots

time slots

The DSS will be used in the short term to allocate check-in time slots in
a way which achieves effective management of queues and utilization of the desks; in the longer term it will inform the allocation of take-off times.

technical lit. about flights_time slots
So, even though she was not late, they would not let her board [the plane?]

Thanks, does that mean that "by the time she made it to the front she was inside the check-in cutoff time" means "by the time she made it to the front it was before the check-in deadline"?

@FranckDernoncourt I made a mistake. I just fixed it. No, it was after the check-in deadline in the time slot between the end of the time allowed and when the flight or ship leaves. After 2:45 in my example.
